# Iterator for Set using HashMap won't produce the value / key?

Tags: java, hashmap, set, maze

Given the following code :

```
public class Game {



    private Map<String,Coordinate> m_myHashMap;
... // more code 
}

public Game(Display display,int level) 
{
        this.m_myHashMap = new HashMap<String,Coordinate>();
... // more code 

}
```

class Coordinate

package model;

```
public class Coordinate {

    private int xCoordinate;
    private int yCoordinate;
    private int sign;

    public Coordinate(int x,int y)
    {
        this.xCoordinate = x;
        this.yCoordinate = y;
        this.sign = 0;
    }

    public int getXCoordinate()
    {
        return this.xCoordinate;
    }

    public int getYCoordinate()
    {
        return this.yCoordinate;
    }

    public void setSign(int number)
    {
        this.sign = number;
    }

    public int getSign()
    {
        return this.sign;
    }

    public void setXcoordinate(int newX)
    {
        this.xCoordinate = newX;

    }

    public void setYcoordinate(int newY)
    {
        this.yCoordinate = newY;

    }

}
```

And a method of Game class :

```
private void placeTreasuresInMaze(PaintEvent e)
{
    // e.gc.drawPolygon(new int[] { 25+x,5+y,45+x,45+y,5+x,45+y });
    int numberOfTreasures = this.m_numberOfPlayers * 3;  // calculate number of treasures 
    Set set = this.m_myHashMap.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();     

    while (numberOfTreasures > 0 && iterator.hasNext())
    {
        numberOfTreasures--;
        // need to add more code here 

    }
}
```

`HashMap` doesn't have an iterator , so I used Set in order to get the elements of the hashmap. 
My problem started when I wanted to iterate on the values of the `HashMap` , but since that's not possible , I tried with `Set` , but `Set` returns an `Object` and not the `Coordinate` object itself . 
Is there a way to get it ?

Regards,Ron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the raw types for the set and iterator - you should use the generic types:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Coordinate>> iterator = m_myHashMap.entrySet()
                                                              .iterator();
```

Or:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, Coordinate>> set = this.m_myHashMap.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Coordinate>> iterator = set.iterator();
```

On the other hand, if you really *do* just want to iterate over the values of the map:

```
Iterator<Coordinate> valueIterator = this.m_myHashMap.values().iterator();
```